# data filtering in matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am a beginner in matlab. I am doing a small project where i am facing issues regarding filtering 
I have a subset of my data below

```
'black' 11  '6/21/2013' <1x1 cell>
'blue'  11  '6/3/2013'  <1x1 cell>
'yellow'12  '4/18/2015' <1x1 cell>
'white' 13  '11/11/2013'<1x1 cell>
'red'   14  '8/4/2014'  <1x1 cell>
'blue'  15  '8/4/2014'  <1x1 cell>
'yellow'16  '12/6/2014' <1x1 cell>
'red'   17  '10/4/2014' <1x1 cell>
'red'   18  '4/17/2015' <1x2 cell>
green'  19  '12/14/2014'<1x1 cell>
orange' 20  '3/18/2015' <1x1 cell>
```

The last column of the data is a cell array which has some values in it which are as below :

```
<1x1 cell>  'b1'    
<1x1 cell>  'c1'    
<1x1 cell>  'b2'    
<1x1 cell>  'c1'    
<1x1 cell>  'b5'    
<1x1 cell>  'd2'    
<1x1 cell>  'f1'    
<1x1 cell>  'f1'    
<1x2 cell>  'b2'    'c1'
<1x1 cell>  'c1'    
<1x1 cell>  'c1'
```

I want to count  the number of occurrences of b1,c1,f1 (the entire data set has values from a to z, a1 to z1 and so on) to between two dates chosen by the user and have the output as

```
from date:
to date: 

      count
f1 
b1
c1
```

thankyou for the help.

Comment: @Adriaan - Thanks for the input,the issue is that i have the letters which start from a to z,i have just shown 3 here (a,b,c ) for example-Thanks for the input,the issue is that i have the letters which start from a to z,i have just shown 3 here (a,b,c ) for example

Answer (score 0):

```
StartDate = input('What is the start date ','s'); % Prompt user for start date
EndDate = input('What is the end date ','s'); % Prompt user for end date
StartDate = datenum(StartDate); % Convert to datenum
EndDate = datenum(EndDate);

a=0;b=0;c=0; % Initalise counters
alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', ....} %EXPAND THIS TO Z
lettercount = zeros(1,numel(alphabet));
for ii = 1:size(YourCell,1)
   celldat = datenum(YourCell{ii,3}); % Get date 
   if celldat > StartDate && celldat < EndDate % Check time boundaries
     for jj = 1:size(YourCell{ii,4})
         tmp = strcmp(YourCell{ii,4}{jj},alphabet);
         lettercount = lettercount + tmp;
     end
   end
end
```

What happens here is that you first prompt the user for the start and end dates of your time interval. You then convert all dates to `datenum` for easy comparison. The counters are initialised and then for each cell the date is checked against the prompted dates, and, if within the time period, the letters are collected in `lettercount`, where `lettercount(1)=a`, `lettercount(2)=b`, etc

Comment: @Adriaan-Thanks for the input,the issue is that i have the letters which start from a to z,i have just shown 3 here (a,b,c ) for example

Comment: I can do that if your cell containing letters contains only 1 letter each time. In your example there's one cell containing 2 letters; it doesnt work then any more.

Comment: No  thats the problem ,I have multiple letters in the cell.

Comment: I added a loop around the inner cell that checks each element one-by-one.

Comment: oh i see! the issues is the letters then.would it be possible then if i have numbers instead of the letters, i can change and then adjust

Comment: What I did now should work, but in general it is better to avoid using strings if possible. This is because the string handling functionality of MATLAB is limited with respect to the numeric handling capabilities.

Comment: ok.thanks for the input.Can u show me an example where say if the letters are  increased from a to z and then i have a1 to z1 and so on with a loop involved